# why select statement based on parameter( IF @SearchType= 0 SELECT...) returns only message "Command(s) completed successfully." and no result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, parameters

I need to display certain number of column depending on what parameter end user is going to use.
First I am declaring a table with SearchTypes based on Parameter then using that value to display necessary columns.
I am using statement

```
  ` IF @SearchType = 0 BEGIN 
    SELECT...
    FROM
    RETURN
    END 
IF @SearchType = 1 BEGIN 
    SELECT...
    FROM
    RETURN
    END 
`
```

But for some reason when I execute the statement I only see

```
Command(s) completed successfully.
```

without any result.

Why cant I simply display `select` statement based on `IF` condition without inserting it into `#TempTable`?

```
DECLARE
       @UserGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '1E82F47B-4C8F-4185-82D2-ED2EB59796D6',
        @LineGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = 'CF144437-F128-4B77-AC19-877247347D02'--'1CB72920-B3FC-4822-8030-37B50A2810EB'--, --WC

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Populating @lineTable with GUIDs 
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

Declare @LineTable Table(GUID uniqueidentifier)
            IF @LineGuid IS NULL
            BEGIN
                  INSERT INTO @LineTable
                  SELECT LineGuid From lstLines
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                  INSERT INTO @LineTable
                  SELECT * FROM dbo.StringOfGuidsToTable(@LineGuid,',')
            END
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--creating @SearchType based on param @LineGUID
--in this example @SearchType gives 0
declare @SearchType  int
set  @SearchType= (select   top 1   
                    CASE WHEN lstLines.LineGUID IN (  
                                                        'D657FDF6-19E1-425B-8598-295083424EFF', --eq access
                                                        'D4983D4A-1D12-461D-8837-6092DC74325B' --eq
                                                    ) then 1
                            WHEN lstLines.LineGUID IN ('F58F7128-18A6-4A3D-AE36-0F30236B4050',--flood
                                                        'E05E7F4A-07C4-4981-BD13-2461D4EE4BF3') then 2--terrorism
                            WHEN lstLines.LineGUID = 'CF144437-F128-4B77-AC19-877247347D02' then 3   --wind 
                            ELSE 0 end as SearchType

from                tblQuotes 
inner join lstLines ON tblQuotes.LineGUID = lstLines.LineGUID 
where lstLines.Inactive = 0
and  lstLines.LineGUID = @LineGUID)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 IF @SearchType = 0
 BEGIN 
       SELECT DISTINCT 
            TOP 100 PERCENT 
                Column1,
                Column2,
                Column3
                --other columns
         FROM 
                  dbo.tblNoteEntities  (nolock) 
           --some other JOINs here 
         WHERE tq.LineGuid IN (SELECT * FROM @LineTable)
                AND               
                  (@UserGUID IS NULL OR tblNoteRecipients.UserGUID = @UserGUID) 
             ORDER BY  Column1
      RETURN
END
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if @SearchType = 1  --eq and eq access 
BEGIN 
SELECT DISTINCT 
            TOP 100 PERCENT 
                Column4,
                Column5,
                Column6
         FROM 
                  dbo.tblNoteEntities  (nolock) 
           --some other JOINs here 
         WHERE tq.LineGuid IN (SELECT * FROM @LineTable)
                AND               
                  (@UserGUID IS NULL OR tblNoteRecipients.UserGUID = @UserGUID) 
             ORDER BY  Column1
      RETURN
END
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if @SearchType = 3 --And so on
```

Comment: Put `SELECT @SearchType` immediately after the assignment and see what value it has. It will be null if no rows were returned by the top 1 query.

Comment: It works fine, gives me a value. 0,1, or 3. Depending on Parameter. 
Thanks

Comment: You have done as I suggested and verified this or you are just asssuming?

Comment: OH!!! You know, it was returning value 3, but there is no condition for `@SearchType = 3` yet.
Thank you very much Martin! Cant believe I missed that.  Sorry about that. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`@SearchType` value was returning 3, but no SELECT condition was for `@SearchType = 3` made. Thats why I only saw message "Command(s) completed succesfully" without any result